# Why files in Linux can have only one owner?

Tags: linux, file, security, permissions, filesystems

Why in Linux there is impossible to set permissions for multiple specific users? What is the rationale behind that files have 'owners' instead of just set of users (or/and groups) that was permitted to do some operations?

ps
This question is rather theoretical than practical, I just want to understand, what is the reason of 'ownership'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs to [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

The [Traditional Unix permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) work surprisingly well in most situations. However, most Linux filesystems also support *Access Control Lists*. ACLs can be used to give permissions to individual users. See the man page [acl(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

So, there are 3 classes of permissions, owner, group, and global.  (http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)  If you want to set permissions for a file for multiple users, just add them to a group and assign that group to this file.  I think you can get pretty granular if you have a specific need to do so.